# Managing NoSuchElementException StringTokenizer

Tags: java

I would like to manage the `StringTokenizer` `NoSuchElementException` when the username or password fields is not shown but I can not manage it.

```
final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
        usernameAndPassword, ":");

System.out.println(usernameAndPassword);

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String tmp1 = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (tokenizer.nextToken() == null) {
        System.out.println("pas d'username");
        username = "";
    } else {
        username = tmp1;
    }

    String tmp2 = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (tokenizer.nextToken() == null) {
        System.out.println("pas de password");
        password = "";
    } else {
        password = tmp2;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: nextToken removes the actual token from tokenizer (this is important becuase the second time you call nextToken you are actually removing the next token), so you are removing 4 tokens per each iteration of the while loop.


https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextElement--

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do `if (tokenizer.nextToken() == null)` directly before checking if it has more tokens or not.

What do you want to check using the `if` condition? Shouldn't it be `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(tmp2))` instead of `if (tokenizer.nextToken() == null)`?

If you want to scan next set of tokens then you'll have to do something like `if(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() && tokenizer.nextToken() != null)` instead of just doing `tokenizer.nextToken()` as you don't know whether it has more tokens or not.

Comment: I want to manage the exception so not display the exception but replace the value of password by ""

Comment: I understand that, so after you do `String tmp2 = tokenizer.nextToken();` you just have to check whether `tmp` is `null` or not. You don't have to do `tokenizer.nextToken()` again.

Comment: @DiR95 What is the problem that you are facing now? Please edit the question and update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the catch block.

```
try {
    final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
            usernameAndPassword, ":");

    System.out.println(usernameAndPassword);

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String tmp1 = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (tmp1 == null){
            System.out.println("pas d'username");
            username = "";
        }
        else{
            username = tmp1;
        }

        String tmp2 = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (tmp2 == null){
            System.out.println("pas de password");
            password = "";
        }
        else{
            password = tmp2;
        }
    }

} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    password = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead :

```
final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
        usernameAndPassword, ":");

System.out.println(usernameAndPassword);

while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    String tmp1 = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (tmp1 == null){
        System.out.println("pas d'username");
        username = "";
    }
    else{
        username = tmp1;
    }

    String tmp2 = tokenizer.nextToken();

    if (tmp2 == null){
        System.out.println("pas de password");
        password = "";
    }
    else{
        password = tmp2;
    }
}
```

When you intiliaze your string tokenizer it splits the string with the colon. So suppose you have a string A:B, it will get tokenised as A and B. You can fetch the value A and B using the nextToken() method. Whenever you call this method the pointer goes to the next element. In the above code you are using this method 4 times. After 2 time the pointer tries to fetch a value but does not succeed and hence the exception.

Thanks

Comment: I modify my code with your code but i have always the NoSuchElementException error...

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the value of variable usernameAndPassword contains a colon or else it is bound to give that exception. Let me know if it still doesnt help

Comment: I want to manage the exception so not display the exception but replace the value of password by ""

Comment: This answer is wrong: if there is no token, then the `nextToken` method throws a NoSuchElementException. It does **not** return null.